# How can I pass a default argument to Rails lambda/scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

I have this piece of code on my accounts model.

```
 scope :unverified, lambda { |limit|
  select('accounts.id, accounts.email').joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN verifications v ON v.account_id = accounts.id')
    .where('v.account_id IS NULL').limit(limit)
}
```

Because my team has rubocop with strict settings, I cannot write it the normal way rails recommends which would look like this:

```
scope :unverified, -> (limit = nil) { 
  select('accounts.id, accounts.email').joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN verifications v ON v.account_id = accounts.id')
    .where('v.account_id IS NULL').limit(limit)
}
```

Writing it the normal way will trigger a rubocop error. I have the code close to the way I want  but I can't figure out how exactly to pass in a default argument for a lambda. Can someone provide just a little push?

Comment: simply do `lambda { |limit = nil| `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply provide the defaults to the block parameters:

```
scope :unverified, lambda { |limit = nil|
  select('accounts.id, accounts.email').joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN verifications v ON v.account_id = accounts.id')
    .where('v.account_id IS NULL').limit(limit)
}
```

But not sure if it makes sense to pass `nil` to `.limit()`. You may want to default it to an `integer`.

Comment: giving `nil` to `limit` is okay: it will not limit the results. So if nothing is given, all the results will be returned.